# In C# and ECMA-CIL, can a struct-instantiated generic be implemented using boxing?

Tags: c#, generics, bytecode, semantics, cil

ECMA-CIL allows generic instances to actually yield a different implementation of the generic definition when instantiated. The instantiation can be specialized based on the chosen generic arguments.

Is there any case where a generic may behave differently if instantiated by a struct instead of an object reference? This is a question regarding semantics; I am not talking about performance.

In other words, could a naive implementation of ECMA-CIL decide to implement struct-instantiated generics as boxed values (as in Java)?

I read ECMA-CIL, but I'm still not sure about this. Any feedback is more than appreciated. Although I'm particularly interested in what happens at the bytecode level, an answer from the C# language perspective is also valuable.

Comment: Yes, it could box them (although it doesn't in current implementations). Equally it could box *all structs*. Boxing is an implementation detail, and should not concern you. The semantics will be the same regardless.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for your answer :) By any chance, do you have any source to support this? I'm working on formal verification of CIL, and any documentation would be useful.  

AFAIK, in C#, a struct cannot have a user-defined parameterless constructor, although at bytecode level it can have one. Thus, ldlocs may cause implicit side-effects when the constructors are called. Perhaps this could be a pathological example of semantical differences that would not happen if boxed values are used. I think this does not apply to bytecode generated from C#. What do you think about it? Thanks again

Comment: I fail to understand how `ldloc` is relevant to the parameterless constructor: all it does is load the variable onto the stack. In C# (at least up to version 7) the parameterless constructor is not called, and it just initializes the variable to `default`. I also don't understand how it's relevant to boxing: whether the CLR actually boxes generic structs is an implementation detail, and there by definition can be no semantic difference. The spec for CLI is here https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf

Comment: I guess I'm just not quite sure what you are asking. If you are asking whether the *semantics* of boxing would be applied, meaning that a mutable struct would not be modified, then absolutely not. A conforming CLI implementation *must* behave the same. If you are asking whether a conforming implementation could store all structs on the heap, then yes it could. It could store them on the Moon (which is made of cheese), as long as the semantics are the same. Performance would suffer obviously, which is why implementations don't do this.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks again. I mentioned ldloc because it copies the struct value it holds at the top of the stack. I thought that this copy operation could call the parameterless constructor. Thus, if it has a user-defined implementation, it may have side effects. These side effects cannot be triggered if boxing is used. If boxed, ldloc copies the boxed reference but not the already boxed value. My mistake was assuming that ldloc may implicitly call a constructor for struct types. I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: No, why would it call it? There is no reason for it to do so, because `default` of a struct does not call the constructor, unless you explicitly call it in CIL. Also, like I said: semantics must be maintained, so if structs are stored on the heap then all reads of structs would require a copy of the box not the reference. In this respect, it would not behave like normal boxing. This is all in theory: there are no implementations that do this for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simulated boxed value type in C#:

```cs
public class Boxed<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value; // do not assign to!

    public Boxed(T value) => Value = value;
}
```

This is the best we can do at .NET level, since there is no native way to make a boxed value type reference (C++/CLI uses a tagged `object` to specify that). This is also more or less equivalent to `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StrongBox<T>`.

> Is there any case where a generic may behave differently if instantiated by a struct instead of an object reference? This is a question regarding semantics; I am not talking about performance.

Of course, using `Boxed<T>` means that `default(Boxed<T>)` is `null` for example. Here is a situation where this could be an issue:

```cs
public static class GlobalVariable<T>
{
    public T Value;
}
```

If .NET actually implemented `GlobalVariable<int>` using `GlobalVariable<Boxed<int>>`, the `Value` field would contain `null` instead of `0`. A conforming CLI implementation would have to implicitly use `Value = new Boxed<T>(default(T));` when the type is instantiated, or modify `ldfld` (or `ldflda`) to create such an instance there if there is `null` (wreaking havoc for threading and `readonly`).

Another issue is copy semantics of value types. Each opcode like `ldloc` or similar assumes that a value type would be copied and mutating the value of the target should not affect the source. For example:

```cs
public static class GlobalVariable<T>
{
    public T Value;

    public delegate void Mutator(ref T value);

    public static T MutateCopy(Mutator mutator)
    {
        var copy = Value;
        mutator(ref copy);
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Calling something like `GlobalVariable<Boxed<ValueTuple<int>>>.MutateCopy` would pose an issue (if the runtime actually translated `mutator(ref copy)` to something like `mutator(ref copy.Value)` in order to call the delegate) since it would access the same instance. The runtime would have to "clone" `Value` as an object during the assignment in order to fix it.

---

Summed up, a value type type argument *could* be implemented using boxing, but without any additional special treatment, you get the same issues you would get in Java when using wrapper classes. It could work without mutable value types or strict null conversion checks (and potentially without byref parameters), but anything more than that will require additional (and complicated) changes to the implementation or languages. For an example of such a thing, see "unboxed" *reference* types in C++/CLI (i.e. reference types without the hat `^`, which have value semantics).